# Почему встроенный ftp-клиент в Ubuntu удаляет файлы

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ftp

После обновления на 23.10 встроенный клиент почему-то начал удалять файлы после их редактирования. Проблема не постоянная и проявляется время от времени. Пробовал редактировать файлы напрямую на хостинге, в этом случае проблем нет. Другие клиенты пока не пробовал. Очень привык к встроенному клиенту и не хотелось бы менять его.

Comment: Возможно, у пользователя было недостаточно прав, чтоб создавать что-то или редактировать, хотя былаб сразу ошибка) странно... ps.. ftp именно не юзал уже лет 10+.. всегда **sftp**

Comment: Да уж, очень странно. У меня тоже через sftp настроена связь